# Why i am getting buffer overflow in this code?

Tags: c, string, pointers, stack, buffer-overflow

```
typedef struct
{
    int top;
    char *arr;
}adjacent;

char *removeDuplicates(char * S)
{
    int count = 0;
    adjacent *ptr = malloc(sizeof(adjacent));
    ptr->top = 0;
    ptr->arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(S));

    ptr->arr[0] = S[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < strlen(S); i++)
    {
        if(ptr->arr[ptr->top] == S[i])
        {
            count--;
            ptr->top = (ptr->top) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            ptr->top = (ptr->top) + 1;
            ptr->arr[ptr->top] = S[i];
        }
    }
    ptr->arr[count + 1] = '\0';
    return ptr->arr;
}
```

The error i am receiving is on website leetcode.com.
The question was to remove all adjacent duplicates from a string.
Given a string S of lowercase letters, a duplicate removal consists of choosing two adjacent and equal letters, and removing them.

We repeatedly make duplicate removals on S until we no longer can.

Return the final string after all such duplicate removals have been made.  It is guaranteed the answer is unique.

ERROR:

```
Runtime Error
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000004f at pc 0x0000004018ae bp 0x7ffed3a16300 sp 0x7ffed3a162f8
READ of size 1 at 0x60200000004f thread T0
    #2 0x7f9d2765f2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)
0x60200000004f is located 1 bytes to the left of 6-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000056)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f9d28ae92b0 in malloc (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xe82b0)
    #3 0x7f9d2765f2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 07 fa fa fa 00 00 fa[fa]06 fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==29==ABORTING
```

Comment: Why are you using a separate struct for this? Just declare top and arr in the function.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(S));` is off-by-one in the event that no characters are removed. There is no allowance for the `NUL` terminator that you write.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @klutt, you have a memory leak in not `free`ing `ptr` which cannot be done outside the function.

Comment: When if(ptr->arr[ptr->top] == S[i]) is true the first time (ptr->top == 0), then ptr->top will be set to -1.  The negative value will then be used as the array index the next time through the loop.

Comment: @jmq that is what my answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the off-by-one allocation, the memory leak, and the unnecessary duplication of `count` and `arr->top` there is a **more serious** issue.

Suppose the second character is the same as the first. The index is reduced to `-1`. Then when you check the next character, it is no longer checking the previous character, but indexing out of range.

The whole technique is in error. Instead of playing with indices, just increment it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *removeDuplicates(char * S)
{
    char *arr = malloc(strlen(S) + 1);      // fix the off-by-one
    if (arr == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(S[index] != '\0') {
        int duplic = 0;
        while(S[index + duplic + 1] == S[index]) {
            duplic++;
        }
        if(duplic == 0) {
            arr[count++] = S[index];
        }
        index += duplic + 1;
    }
    arr[count] = '\0';
    return arr;
}

int main()
{   
    char s[100] = "";
    while(strcmp(s, "q") != 0) {
        scanf(" %99[^\n]", s);
        char *result = removeDuplicates(s);
        printf("[%s]\n", result);
        free(result);
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
aaab
[b]
abbb
[a]
abba
[aa]
aabbaa
[]
q
[q]
```

Comment: I think the question is not clear, take this example: Example 1:

Input: "abbaca"
Output: "ca"
Explanation: 
For example, in "abbaca" we could remove "bb" since the letters are adjacent and equal, and this is the only possible move.  The result of this move is that the string is "aaca", of which only "aa" is possible, so the final string is "ca".

Comment: @AdityaNaitan I edited the code following misunderstanding the task.